# Using a variable period in an interval in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, variables, intervals, period

I have a relation that maintains monthly historical data. This data is added to the table on the last day of each month. A service I am writing can then be called specifying a month and a number of months prior for which to retrieve the historical data. I am doing this by creating startDate and endDate variables, and then returning data between the two. The problem I am having is that startDate is a variable number of months before endDate, and I cannot figure out how to use a variable period in an interval.

Here is what I have:

```
    DECLARE
      endDate   TIMESTAMP := (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',$2) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') - INTERVAL '1 DAY';
      startDate TIMESTAMP := endDate - INTERVAL $3 'MONTH';
```

I know that the line for startDate is not correct. How is this properly done?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Use this line:

```
startDate TIMESTAMP := endDate - ($3 || ' MONTH')::INTERVAL;
```

and note the space before `MONTH`. 
Basically: You construct a string with like `4 MONTH` and cast it with `::type` into a proper interval.

**Edit**: I' have found another solution: You can calculate with `interval` like this:

```
startDate TIMESTAMP := endDate - $3 * INTERVAL '1 MONTH';
```

This looks a little bit nicer to me.

Comment: Or:  `endDate - '1 mon'::interval * $3` (less casting & concatenating)

Comment: @A.H. Cool :) Remember to [@reply in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) or I may miss your answer.

Comment: The multiplication with the interval is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 11):

This code has nothing directly to do with your situation, but it does illustrate how to use variables in INTERVAL arithmetic. My table's name is "calendar".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_param(num_months integer)
  RETURNS SETOF calendar AS
$BODY$

    select * from calendar
    where cal_date <= '2008-12-31 00:00:00'
    and cal_date > date '2008-12-31' - ($1 || ' month')::interval;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

While the above accepted answer is fine, it's a little bit antiquated - requiring a bit more mental energy to read than needed if you're running on Postgres 9.4+.

### Old Way (Postgres Versions < 9.4)

```
startDate TIMESTAMP := endDate - $3 * INTERVAL '1 MONTH';
```

### New Way (Postgres 9.4+)

```
startDate TIMESTAMP := endDate - MAKE_INTERVAL(MONTHS => $3);
```

If you are on [Postgres 9.4+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html), the new [MAKE_INTERVAL()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function seems much more readable - probably why they created it.

*If you want something you can run in your editor, here are a couple of
examples (I substituted the original variable binding `$3` with the number `2` for an example of 2-months prior to the current date).*

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 2 * INTERVAL '1 MONTH';

SELECT CURRENT_DATE - MAKE_INTERVAL(MONTHS => 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way I have found to pass a variable time period to Postgres is similar to A.H.'s answer: by multiplying by an integer. But this can be done without a cast.

Python example (with *sqlalchemy* and *pandas*):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection = sa.create_engine(connection_string)

df = pd.read_sql(
   sa.text('''
       select * from events
       where
       event_date between now() - (interval '1 day' * :ndays) and now()
       limit 100;
'''),
   connection,
   params={'ndays': 100}
)
```

The number of days (*ndays*) is passed as an integer from within Python - so unintended consequences are less likely.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is like this.. It gives me option to set specific date or a relative range.

```
create or replace function search_data(_time_from timestamptz default null, _last_interval text default null)
    returns setof journal
    language plpgsql as
$$
begin
    return query
        select *
        from journal
        where created >= case
                             when _time_from is not null
                                 then _time_from
                             else now() - _last_interval::interval end;
end;
$$;
```