# Add number of days in given date

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL:

Let say:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW())+interval '1 day';
```

It will show date tomorrow.

Problem:
While I having a column `duration` in table `tbl`, following SQL does not work :

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW())+interval duration || ' day' from tbl;
```

I just wondering how to make the '1 day' become a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: very similar question and good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796657/using-a-variable-period-in-an-interval-in-postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to make '1day' a variable, just multiply it by duration variable:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()+duration * INTERVAL '1day') FROM tbl;
```