# passing parameter to java prepare statement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jar

I'm actually trying to execute `delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - interval '5 month'`

I want to pass a parameter `5` to `?`

```
public static final StringBuilder SQL_MY_Query= new StringBuilder(
        "delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - interval '? month'");

ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL_MY_Query.toString());
ps.setInt(1, 5);
```

I'm getting an error `Sql Exception org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.` How do we fix this?

Comment: A question mark inside a string literal is not a parameter placeholder.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796657/using-a-variable-period-in-an-interval-in-postgres

Comment: if column index is out of range, does the table exist? 0 columns...

Comment: @ThoFin No it is the index of the parameter in the query (in this case there is no parameter 1 because there are no parameters in the query.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark must replace a token; not be in a string literal.

Try this:

```
public static final StringBuilder SQL_MY_Query= new StringBuilder(
        "delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - interval ? || ' month'");
```

Or (based on: [Using a variable period in an interval in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796657/using-a-variable-period-in-an-interval-in-postgres) ):

```
public static final StringBuilder SQL_MY_Query= new StringBuilder(
        "delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - (? || ' month')::interval");
```

Comment: Have you tried this, the link I posted in the comments suggest it should be `(? || ' month')::interval`

Comment: I don't have postgresql at hand right now, so we are actually in the same boat ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the below might help. Have a look.

**Option 1:** 
        delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - interval ? "

> ps.setString(1, numMonth + " month");

**Option 2:** 
        delete from mytable where CreationDate < now() - interval (? || ' month')"

> ps.setString(1, numMonth);