# ERROR 13540 --- [ restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker unexpected token: DAY

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

As it gives unexpected token: DAY. Anybody suggest what should be the alternative of DAY here

```
select p from Patient p where p.id in(select a.patient.id from p.assessments a where (a.appointmentDate <=(CURRENT_DATE + interval 6 DAY) and a.appointmentDate >=(CURRENT_DATE)) and a.chatBotStatus='LINK_CREATED')
```

As I am new in data JPA so any answer will be appreciable

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try using native query something like this:

```
@Query(value = "select * from activation_codes a where a.type = :type and a.id_account = :id_account and a.creation_time <= NOW() - :hoursAgo * INTERVAL '1 hour'", nativeQuery = true)
```

please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954042/4076451