# How to pass date as parameter from php to postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

i have the following request:

```
 select * from newagenda where 
     debut >'$1' AND debut < date '$1' + interval '24 hours' and
     agendaid=$2'
```

which fails with a type cast error...

```
 failed: the error: = FEHLER: ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ timestamp:
```

i try to translate: ERROR: invalid inputsyntax for type timestamp:

before i parametrized, i had

```
 select * from newagenda where debut >'$adate' AND debut < date '$adate' +
     interval '24 hours' and agendaid=$agid;
```

which worked perfectly well.....

now, the date comes back through a post request from a web request, so can inherently be manipulated, that's why  would like to parametrize it, but i am clueless on how to get this to work.....

i tried

```
 select * from newagenda where 
     debut >'$1'::DATE AND debut < date '$1'::DATE + interval '24 hours' and
     agendaid=$2'
```

or

```
$largs = array($isodate."::DATE");
```

also

```
$largs = array("'".$isodate."'::DATE");
```

but nothing worked......
how can i get this get to work? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you translate the error message?

Comment: The first query has an obvious syntax error (typo here?) but even without, that is not a parametrized query...

Comment: could you please point out the obvious error?

Comment: Can you not use PDO ?

Comment: and the proper SQL format for a date/time is `date('Y-m-d G:i:s')`

Comment: how would PDO impact the fact that i can't get my query right? as far as i see it, it would recquire a lot of rewriting, and adding just another layer on top of this than can fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along the lines of :

```
<?php

//using single quoates to make sure the variables aren't expanded
$sql = 'select * from newagenda 
        where 
            debut >$1::DATE 
            AND debut < date $2::DATE
            and agendaid=$3';

$formattedDate = new \DateTime($date);
$rangeStart = $formattedDate->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$formattedDate->add('1 day');
$rangeEnd = $formattedDate->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');

pg_prepare($con,'sel_from_agenda', $sql);
pg_execute($con,'sel_from_agenda', [$rangeStart, $rangeEnd, $agid]);
```

I using functional connections here but it would probably be best to use OO or PDO.

Comment: Thanks, that works, even without the casts, but this means i can't use the postgres functions ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to ? `pg_prepare($con,'sel_my_func', 'select myFumction($1, $2)');`

Comment: Ah i meant the date manipulations directly in the sql request

Comment: I see, in that case, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796657/using-a-variable-period-in-an-interval-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pomm-project/foundation` library take advantage of the parameters (and results) converters and by the way use the range type and operators:

```php
$pomm = new PommProject\Foundation\Pomm(['db' => ['dsn' => 'pgsql://user@host/db_name']]);

$date = new \Datetime(); // set your date here
$query = <<<SQL
select * from newagenda
where
  tsrange($*::timestamp, $*::timestamp + '1 day'::interval, '()') @> debut
  and agendaid = $*
SQL;
$iterator = $pomm['db']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query($query, [$date, $date, 123]);

foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```