# How to pass the number of days to a Postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

Argument `days` in function `getAvgByDay()` doesn't work, I guess because it is inside quotes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAvgByDay(days int)
RETURNS TABLE ( average text,
                date timestamp with time zone
               ) AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT to_char( AVG(measure), '99999D22') AS average, ( now() - interval '$1 day') AS date
FROM (
        SELECT mes.date, mes.measure
        FROM measures mes
        WHERE mes.date < ( now() - interval '$1 day')
    ) AS mydata;
END
$func$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I am trying to create a procedure like sql server

Comment: Please provide the table definition (`CREATE TABLE measures ...`) and always your version of Postgres. Why the name "date" for a `timestamptz` column? That's confusing / misleading.

Comment: Worth a read: [Using a variable period in an interval in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7796657/2943403)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the column `measures.date` is actually data type `timestamptz` and not a `date`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_avg_by_day(_days int)
  RETURNS TABLE (average text, ts timestamptz) AS  -- not using "date" for a timestamp
$func$
SELECT to_char(avg(measure), '99999D22') -- AS average
     , now() - interval '1 day' * $1     -- AS ts
FROM   measures m
WHERE  m.date < now() - interval '1 day' * $1
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

- No need for PLpgSQL, can be a simper SQL function.

  - [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)
- No need for a subquery. Only adds complexity and cost for no gain.
- No need for column aliases in the outer query level. Those are not used, as visible column names are defined in the `RETURNS` clause.
- No need for extra parentheses. [Operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) works as desired anyway. (No harm in this case, either.)
- Don't use CaMeL case identifier in Postgres if you can avoid it.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- Don't call a `timestamptz` column "date". That's misleading. Using "ts" instead.
- Most importantly: You suspected as much, and "sticky bit" already explained: no interpolation inside strings. But just multiply the time unit with your `integer` input to subtract the given number of days:

  ```
  interval '1 day' * $1
  ```

  That's faster and cleaner than string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no interpolation in strings. But you can concatenate strings and cast them to an interval. Try:

```
... concat(days, ' day')::interval ...
```

Or you could use `format()`, that's probably a little closer to what you originally had:

```
... format('%s day', days)::interval ...
```

Comment: wait a moment I understand but I am not expert in postgres a bit more help please

Comment: I would like you can write for me the correct format for this line:  ( now() - interval '$1 day') AS date

Comment: @asterix: Replace `interval '$1 day'` with what I wrote to get for example `(now() - concat(days, ' day')::interval)`.